# Functional ode solution method and uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I stumbled on a fun Olympiad question...
Are there nontrivial solutions of $f'= f(f(x))$?

So I guessed a power law $f(x)=cx^a$ and easily found $a=c=-1$.

Two questions:

> Is there a systematic way of approaching this question. Guessing seems rather crude.

And

> Is this solution unique?

Comment: Your solution is incorrect, $f(x) = \frac{-1}{x} \implies f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ but $f(f(x)) = \frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{x}} = x$

Comment: Thanks. I made a bonehead algebra mistake! And compounded it by not checking. There is a power law solution but it comes out complex.

Comment: I'd like to see a reference for that Olympiad. It must have been a lot of fun.

Comment: I only saw the problem statement without citation or solution

Comment: The correct power law solution is f=cx^a where a+1/a =1 and c=a^(1/a).